# How to properly install MEEP in Google Colab?

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, meep

In the past I have installed the pymeep package in Google Colab with the following cell:

```
!wget -c https://repo.continuum.io/miniconda/Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh
!chmod +x Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh
!bash ./Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh -b -p ./anaconda
import os
os.environ['PATH'] += ":/content/anaconda/bin"
!conda create -n mp -c conda-forge pymeep
import sys
sys.path.append('/content/anaconda/envs/mp/lib/python3.7/site-packages/')
```

Which is an exact copy from this website: https://rf5.github.io/2019/12/22/meep-intro.html

Sometimes the code I wrote doesn't work. It executes without errors, but when I try to execute `import meep as mp`. I get the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-f30f3b609667> in <module>()
----> 1 import meep

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'meep'

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NOTE: If your import is failing due to a missing package, you can
manually install dependencies using either !pip or !apt.

To view examples of installing some common dependencies, click the
"Open Examples" button below.
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Is there a better way of installing meep or rather pymeep in Google Colab?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace 3.7 with 3.8 as the latest python version installed using conda is 3.8

```
sys.path.append('/content/anaconda/envs/mp/lib/python3.8/site-packages/')
```

[`Example`](https://gist.github.com/venky18/e24df1e55502e2d6523881b3f71c0bff)